Will downgrading my Android 14 to 13 remove the vertical green on the screen?
Vertical Green Lines:

I've been collecting information from any resources as to how to fix those sudden green lines (there's another colour) on the screen that appeared out of nowhere. My phone is Samsung Galaxy A73 5G with android 14. Previously, it was android 12 when I bought it 4 months ago. It has never been dropped on a hard surface nor fell in the water. It even has no scratches.
Some resources say it was because overheating that caused the green lines. I refuse to believe that. My old J7+ with the same brand never got any issue such as those green lines. I even often used it to play a game with a charger plugged in! If it were because of the overheating, then why was my old phone just fine?
The other possibility is water. They say that the water could cause the green lines. I don't believe it either. According to this site, samsung A73 is water and dust resistant. I barely let my phone get water on it. I even never dropped my phone in the water. Even my old samsung without water resistant has ever been dropped in the water several times never got green lines!
Some sites suggest it was because of the update. So, I'm preparing to downgrade my software from 14 to 13 with the hope that it will remove the green lines. But, of course I need some advice if this were a right thing to do, were it?
I'm even starting to think that all those vertical green lines are just marketing strategy from Samsung to get more money by forcing the users to replace their LCD! That was evil!

Are the lines always visible also while booting or only at the end of the booting process and when the phone becomes usable? If they are always visible it is with a very high percent a hardware damage. Hardware can get damaged without anything causing it.

@Robert they will be visible as long as the screen is on even while booting or charging in shut down. Could this only be fixed by replacing the LCD with the new one?

Could this only be fixed by replacing the LCD with the new one? YES

Downgrading from Android 14 to Android 13 will most likely not fix this problem.  It's almost certainly a hardware problem.  The problem is likely with the screen itself or with the small connector to the screen.  What you're seeing is the result of dysfunctional signal pins for 3 LCD columns or a short within the LCD matrix itself causing this effect.
